# Ubuntu login error in virtual box after removing python 3

Tags: virtualbox, python

I have installed ubuntu in Virtual box and my machine was working correctly but when i have uninstalled or remove python3 i am getting this window and able to login again.

[image]

Comment: Removing Python3 is a reliable way to destroy your Ubuntu system...

Comment: do i have to reinstall ubuntu then?

Comment: Yes, or restore a snapshot. This is probably the easiest way to fix.

Comment: Many of Ubuntu Desktop features rely on `python3` (and it needs to be the version the system comes with), thus removing it will cause much of the desktop to fail to operate.  You can still login using the text terminal (ie. use the system as a text based server) allowing you to reverse the changes you made; though re-install is usually faster if you're learning or *skillset* is limited.

Comment: I removed engine from my car and now it doesn't start ;-)

Comment: how can i reverse the changes? as i logged in to ubuntu text based server. Do i have to reinstall python 3?

Comment: Ask the person who made the changes, they should know what they did (*thus having clues as to what needs to be reversed*). If they don't remember, searching the logs should remind them (`apt` logs can be found in `/var/log/apt/history.log`), as you need to reverse the changes made and we didn't make any changes so can't tell you what was done.